# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have my build.gradle(app) as:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dpka.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and build.gradle(project) as:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and I am getting the error:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 12.0.1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have changed the version of com.google.android.gms to 12.0.1(as shown in the code above), but still it's showing me this error, what should I do?

Comment: By the way, `firebase-auth:12.0.0` needs to use `12.0.1`

Comment: oh my bad! Thankyou! :)
I made the changes but now in, 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
It's saying to use exact same version specification.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the new Gradle file and build output. Also, I suggest that you remove `play-services:12.0.1'` and only compile the Google services you actually plan on using. For example, just Maps. See second blue box here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @cricket_007 Hey! Unfortunately I am unable to post questions, but I wanted to ask one, I want to check if the date(I have in a variable) is a Sunday or not, how can I do this? Please guide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
```

all firebase dependencies need to be the same version.